# Gradle: How to add resource (not lib) jars to root of war?

Tags: jar, gradle, war, build.gradle

In the continuing saga of attempting to migrate from an insanely complicated ant build to gradle - We have some resource jar files for 'javahelp' that I'm generating.  They contain no classes.  I need to add the output of the project that creates these resource jars to the *root* of my war (not to `WEB-INF/lib`).

My attempted solution:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

//Move files into position for the mmplEar project
task stage(overwrite: true, dependsOn: war) << {
}

war {
    from project(':help:schedwincli').buildDir.absolutePath + '/libs'
    include '*.jar'
}

dependencies {
    //Ensure the jar is generated, but we don't want it in the lib dir
    providedCompile project(':help:schedwincli')
}
```

This compiles and runs, and the `:help:schedwincli` does run and generate the needed jar, however when I open up my war file, the expected jar is not present anywhere in the war.  Suggestions?

**Edit**

I made the changes suggested by Peter below, but now I get this error:

> Could not find property 'resources' on configuration container.

This is where it says it's failing:

```
from '../../runtime', /*Fails on this line*/
    '../../runtime/html',
    '../../runtime/html/Jboss',
    '../../runtime/props',
    '../../runtime/props/Jboss',
    '../../scripts',
    '../../../proj/runtime',
    '../../../proj/runtime/html',
    '../../../proj/runtime/html/Jboss',
    '../../../proj/runtime/props',
    '../../../proj/runtime/props/Jboss',
    configurations.resources
include '*.css'
include '*.gif'
include '*.html'
include '*.jpg'
include '*.jnlp'
include '*.props'
include '*.properties'
include 'jsps/**'
include '*.jar'
include 'log4j/**'
include 'setupLdap.cmd'
include 'spreadsheets/*.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like:

```
configurations {
    resources 
}

dependencies {
    resources project(':help:schedwincli')
}

war {
    from configurations.resources
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm now getting an error:  `Could not find property 'resources' on configuration container.`  See edit to my code

Comment: Looks like you forgot to declare the configuration as I did, or you didn't declare it in time.

Comment: I copied & pasted the configuration block into my build file.  Does this configuration block need to be declared at a higher level?

Comment: What do you mean by "or you didn't declare it in time"?

Comment: ok, nevermind.  I thought I'd try changing the configuration name from `resources` to `helpJars` because I was thinking maybe resources might be conflicting with the war task's source/main/resources sourceset or something (not sure why it would but figured it didn't hurt anything to try).  That fixed the problem.

Comment: You can change the name to whatever you like as long as you change it everywhere.

Comment: Yeah.  Not sure why `resources` didn't work but it's going now.  Thanks!

Comment: Peter - was wondering if I could draw your attention to another of my questions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692016/gradle-ear-deploymentdescriptor-exclude-module-from-application-xml