# Gradle: ear deploymentDescriptor - Exclude module from application.xml

Tags: gradle, ear, build.gradle

I have the following in my gradle build file.  My problem is that log4j.properties is being added as an ejb module in application.xml, despite my attempt to remove it from the xml per the thread here:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/ear_plugin_inserts_unneeded_ejb_modules_in_the_application_xml_ear_descriptor

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

ear {

    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = 'ourapp'
        displayName = 'ourapp'
        initializeInOrder = true

            //This doesn't work:
        withXml { xml ->
            xml.asNode().module.removeAll { it.ejb.text.equals('log4j.properties') }
        }
    }
    //Add log4j.properties to ear root
    from('../../lib/log4j.properties', 'log4jProperties')
}


dependencies
{
    deploy 'javax:javax.jnlp:1.2'
    deploy 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:1.6.0'

    earlib 'org.apache:apache-log4j:1.2.16'
}
```

How can I get the gradle to exclude log4j.properties from application.xml?

**EDIT**

This is causing a failure to start up in my application server (JBoss 6.0.0) because it doesn't know what to do with log4j.properties.  I can work around it by manually creating my application.xml file, but that makes for another thing that has to be maintained.  Any assistance would be welcome!

Comment: Have you tried `it.ejb.text().equals` notice the parentheses after text.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings that had no effect

Comment: Try `xml.asNode().module.removeAll { true }` just for testing, if now all modules are missing you only have to work on the matching logic. And could you add the relevant parts of the generated descriptor.

Comment: Time constraints forced me to just run with a pre-built application.xml.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. You need to protect the 'remove' method with an 'if' block because the closure is called multiple times. I found that the first time its called, log4jNode is set to 'null'.

```
withXml {
    def log4jNode = asNode().module.find { it.ejb.text() == 'log4j.properties' }
    if (log4jNode) {
        asNode().remove( log4jNode )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Too bad you came along too late for me to award the bounty to you, but still much appreciated